# Google Appengine: Budget and Daily Spending Limit not Working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, billing, app-engine-flexible

I am using flexible environment.
I setup a billing account and set the following:

- Budget: 0.01$
- Daily Spending Limit: 0.01$

But I am already being charged 5$. How is that possible? This is the line which tells me where the charges are comming from:

```
App Engine  Flex Instance Core Hours    5,769 Minutes   $5.06
App Engine  Flex Instance RAM   96.15 GB-hour   $0.68
Google Compute  Storage PD Capacity 1.43 GB-month   $0.06
```

This is what my budget looks like

```
Specified amount    This billing account    50% 
$7.25 / $0.01
```

as you can see it shows a even higher charge..

I thought if you set a daily spending limit/budget it will just stop serving request and wait until the free quota is available again the next day.. That is what I want for now, I don't need this server running 24/7 at the moment and charging my card.

I disabled the application for now, but that can't be a solution.. I don't want to have to disable/enable the server every time I want to work on it. Do I have to unlink my credit card? I just want the server to stop overcharging me, and stop serving requests once the free quota is over.

This is what I have set in the AppEngine panel

```
Enabled (Daily spending limit: $0.01) Settings
Quotas reset every 24 hours. Next reset: 12 hrs
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please have a look at following link

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs

For me it sounds that spending limit is only available for the standard environment and not for the flexible environment.

Anyway application at the flexible environment are always running 24 hours with one instance and not like the standard enviroment which shutsdown after some time. This behaviour for flexible environment is described in this article

https://medium.com/google-cloud/three-simple-steps-to-save-costs-when-prototyping-with-app-engine-flexible-environment-104fc6736495#.izm31z93r

Answer (score 0):

Even it's standard environment the billing amount is incorrect from time to time in my experience. You'll have to ask the billing support for refund, make sure you ask for escalate the ticket as the junior staffs will just be wasting your time.